# Allow IIS Windows Authenticated User access to custom .net dll

Tags: vb.net, iis, dll, asp-classic, com

I have a classic ASP website that is being hosted by IIS 8.5. The site is only accessible to users in the companies domain (intranet) so we use Windows Authentication. All other authentication types are disabled. I created a vb.net COM dll, that uses OpenXml to create documents and allow the users to download them. The dll was registered using RegAsm. The dll works great for users with Administrative rights to the server, i.e. Me. But when I try to have another user without those rights access the dll, I get an object required error. For testing I have granted full rights to a certain non-admin user, on the website directory and dll files themselves, and still get the error. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Chances are, you are not capturing the actual error. Start by checking Err.Number at every step (with On Error Goto Next, of course), from CreateObject onward, and log the error.

Comment: I commented down by line until I got this error:

Hex: 8007010B 
Description:"The directory name is invalid" 

It lets me create the object with the Server.CreateObject call. The com class has some public properties, and a few different public functions. It lets me call two of the functions without a problem. When I call the final function to create the document. That's the error that occurs.

Comment: That is not a likely a COM or an ASP error but an application bug. Your DLL likely has a bug where it assumes it has access to something (likely write permission to some folder), only available to the Administrators group. You might have to debug the DLL with a non administrator account to figure it out.

Comment: I'm assuming you are using impersonation, otherwise none of it makes sense.

Comment: You are exactly right. I had two errors when I thought I only had one. The first was a permissions error, that I unknowingly fixed. I didn't even realize the new error was on the next line until I went back as you said line by line. The error was in the DLL where I was trying to get a temp file name. Can't believe I didn't think about that first. Thanks!